# How to avoid page scroll in mobile browsers when doing a copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboarddata

I am trying to do a copy to clipboard action by using below code, and the code works fine in desktop browsers but when it comes to mobile browsers like IOS safari/chrome the page scrolls down at `$temp.val(copydatacode).select();`

```
 $('#myelementcopy').click(function(event){         
        var copydatacode= $('.addelement').html();
        var $temp = $("<input>");
        $("body").append($temp);
        $temp.val(copydatacode).select(); // when the code execute at this line the mobile browser jumps to the page bottom                     
        document.execCommand("copy");           
        $temp.remove(); 
        return false;
        event.preventDefault();         
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for a perfect solution to this but right now instead of appending to `body` I append to the element being tapped. This results in a small scroll instead of all the way to the bottom of the page. In jQuery, I used:

```
$(this).append($temp);
```